# Change private python package name while retaining git history

Tags: python, git, setuptools, python-wheel, python-packaging

I have been developing a private python package (my first py package) and want to change the name while retainng all my git commits.

I formatted it in a similar way to [Cookie Cutter Data Science](https://drivendata.github.io/cookiecutter-data-science/) where all the code lives in the `src` dir. This has been fine while building but when upload it to a server or another computer I don't want to have to call it like...

```py
from src.data import *
```

I have tried just renaming it using `git mv src/ newname/` but when I push this change to Github all my files are *lost* (i know they are there but I would prefer to easily see all my past changes). I shared it in the form of a `.whl` file.

So do I just have to rename it and deal with loosing the changes? Or is there a different git command to use. Or is there some configuration in the `setup.py` file i can do?

Here is my `setup.py` for reference.

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='newname',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='...',
    author='...',
    license='MIT',
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
setup(
    …
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    …
)
```

See https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages

Then change your import to

```
from data import *
```